# Extended.Wpf.Toolkit DockingManager, set startup size of panels?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF, and am starting out a new project. I have Extended.Wpf.Toolkit, and a `DockingManager`. I set the `DockWidth` value in the xaml, and see the sizes update. But when i launch the application, the `LayoutAnchorablePane`s start at a different size. Am I missing something to set the size on launch?

```
  <xcad:DockingManager Margin="0,38,0,0" Loaded="FormInit">
            <xcad:LayoutRoot>
                <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                    <xcad:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                          DockHeight="*">
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockWidth="200"
                                            Orientation="Vertical">
                            <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                                <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Setup">
                                    <Label>
                                        <xctk:WrapPanel Name="LeftLoader" />                                      
                                    </Label>
                                </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                            </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockWidth="1000"
                                            Orientation="Vertical">
                            <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                                <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="MidZone">
                                    <Label>
                                        <xctk:WrapPanel Name="MainLoader" />
                                    </Label>
                                </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                            </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>                      
                    </xcad:LayoutPanel>
                    <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup DockHeight="200">
                        <xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                            <xcad:LayoutAnchorable Title="Runtime">
                                <Label>
                                    <xctk:WrapPanel Name="BaseLoader" />
                                </Label>
                            </xcad:LayoutAnchorable>
                        </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                    </xcad:LayoutAnchorablePaneGroup>
                </xcad:LayoutPanel>
            </xcad:LayoutRoot>
        </xcad:DockingManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED by storing a layout file and loading it on load. Thanks to this answer:

[AvalonDock DockingManager does not load layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15970888/avalondock-dockingmanager-does-not-load-layout)

and this code:

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AvalonDock%202.0%20Getting%20Start%20Guide%20PART%202